# C Programming, is there a correct way to have blank spaces in printf?

Tags: c, printf

Here's my code
[image]

The program is supposed to get a 5 digit number from the user and the space the digits apart by 10 spaces. I just added the spaces directly onto the printf line, and it does have the correct output (I think). I was just wondering if there was a "correct" way to do this.

Comment: that would start by pasting your code as text, not as image...

Comment: You can use `%11d` to format each digit with a width of 11 characters. Kind of a hack, though.

Comment: No, no, no, don't put an image of your code in the question, put the actual ***text*** of your code in your question. What is wrong with the operating system you are using that won't let you copy text, paste it into the question and then indent it by 4-spaces so it show up as properly formatted code?

Comment: [don't put images of code here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the width specifier like

```
printf("%11d%11d%11d%11d%11d", digitOne, digitTwo, digitThree, digitFour, digitFive);
```

The `%11d` is to print the digit over a space that would be occupied by 11 characters. Here, you need to print a character and need 10 characters' space. So `%11d` is used instead of `%10d`.

This would print the digits in a right aligned fashion. For the left aligned way, use a `-` in front like

```
printf("%-11d", digitOne);
```

You can also use `*` to specify the width like

```
printf("%*d", 11, digitOne);
```

Read more [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/).